# Accessing struct from double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm currently trying to implement a doubly linked list in C, and am not understanding how to access the struct from a double pointer.

Here is my simple struct:

```
typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node * next;
  struct node * prev;
} node;
```

Here is a simple method where I try to push a value to the front of the list:

```
void push_front(node ** head, int newVal) 
{
  node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

  newNode->val = newVal;
  newNode->next = head;

  *head->prev = newNode;

  *head = newNode;
}
```

However, the line `*head->prev = newNode` gives me an error, saying that the left of `->prev` must point to a `struct/union`. I'm just learning C so maybe I'm overlooking something really easy, but isn't head the pointer to the pointer of my head node? And *head is the pointer to my head node. Which I would assume means `*head->prev` should work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `head` is a pointer to the pointer of your head node. So you can access `->prev` by doing:

```
(*head)->prev = newNode;
```

Without the parentheses, the operator precedence rules of C parse your statement as

```
*(head->prev) = newNode;
```

which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
node ** head
```

Here `head` is a pointer to a pointer and `(*head)` is a pointer.
So you need to access pointer like

```
(*head)->prev = newnode;
```